# How to make json data show up in tabular format for each machine?

Tags: python

I have list of machine and I iterate each machine and make custom url for them and then execute it to get their `JSON` data. `JSON` data for each machine looks like below:

```
[{'latestFile': 'abc.tar', 'activeFile': 'yuqq.tar', 'error': 'some-error-1', 'timestamp': 1234558964}]
```

Now I need to make tabular data like this for each of my machine on my console when I print it along with their IP Address. How can I do this in Python?

```
Machine    Latest File         Active File              Error           Timestamp
------    --------------      ----------------        ----------      --------------
1.2.3.4        abc.tar            yuqq.tar             some-error-1       1234558964
2.1.4.7        def.tar            mkj.tar              some-error-2       1234558964
3.2.3.9        ghi.tar            ysq.tar              some-error-3       1234558964
7.3.8.6        pqe.tar            prq.tar              some-error-4       1234558964
```

There is a possibility that certain fields might not be their in each machine JSON. In that case, I can just leave that column empty for that machine.

Below is my code where I iterate each machine and append JSON response for each machine in `messages` variable but I am not sure how can I get data in above tabular format for each machine. Is this possible to do by any chance?

```
total_machines = len(machines)
messages = []

for machine in machines:
    try:
        ip = machine['ip_address']
        with session.get(
                make_url(env=env, profile=profile, ip=ip)
        ) as response:
            response.raise_for_status()
            machine_json_value = response.json()
        messages.append(machine_json_value)
    except Exception as e:
        messages.append(str(e))

    # how do I make tabular format report for each machine?
```

Basically I just want to format my output in tabular format on the console for all the machines. Any output is fine as long as it is properly formatted and easily readable.

Answer (score 0):

you can use pandas package to convert into dataframe and then you can use print(df) to print the data in tabular structure:

```
In [1]: import pandas as pd                                                     

In [2]: dict1= [{'latestFile': 'abc.tar', 'activeFile': 'yuqq.tar', 'error': 'so
   ...: me-error-1', 'timestamp': 1234558964}]                                  

In [3]: df = pd.DataFrame(dict1)                                                


In [5]: print(df)                                                               
  latestFile activeFile         error   timestamp
0    abc.tar   yuqq.tar  some-error-1  1234558964
```

if you don't want to print the index then:

```
In [6]: print(df.to_string(index=False))                                        
latestFile activeFile         error   timestamp
   abc.tar   yuqq.tar  some-error-1  1234558964
```

As you are storing all the json values in the `messages` variable. You can pass the messages to `pd.DataFrame()` to generate the dataframe.

One change you would need to do it store the exception error is some other variable.

Comment: I want to format it nicely as well just like I have in my above question. Can we do that using this approach? Also I have bunch of machines and I need to do this for all of them. How can I show column only once if we go with this approach for all of the machines?

Comment: you still around?

Comment: if the structure of the json is the same, you can create a list of dictionary first having details of all the machines and then using `pd.DataFrame()` create a single dataframe. In that case, your columns would be displayed only once.

Comment: can you provide an example if possible on that? I have never used panda before so kinda confuse on how that work.